# Calling a different class in the same src folder will not work

Tags: java, oop, methods, constructor

I am trying to call the class, "CarFuel", from the same src folder. It is not working and shows an error.

Code for class with methods for main:

```
public class CarFuel {

    int CarFuel = 5; //Gallons of fuel starting in car


    public CarFuel(int FuelAmount){ //Constructor for defined staring fuel amount
        CarFuel = FuelAmount;
    }

    public void GetGasoline(int amount){ //Filling up gasoline, amount = how much gasoline filled up
        CarFuel = CarFuel + amount;
    }

    public void DrainGasoline(int amount){ //Driving car, amount = how much gasoline drained
        CarFuel = CarFuel - amount;
    }

    public int GetGasoline(){ //returns how much gasoline is left in the end
        return CarFuel;
    }

}

//MAIN EXEX IN CarFuelExec
```

Here is the main class that uses these methods:

```
public class CarFuelExec {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        CarFuel.car = new CarFuel(0);
        car.GetGasoline(36);
        car.DrainGasoline(5);
         System.out.println("The remaining fuel in your car is: " + car.GetGasoline + " gallons");

    }
}
```

Could anybody tell me why CarFuel.car = new Carfuel(0); is not calling the other class and is outputting an error?

Comment: For one, `car.GetGasoline` is missing parenthesis: `car.GetGasoline()`

Comment: For another -- what error are you seeing?

Comment: For two, this isn't C#, so don't capitalize your methods if you'd like to make it easier for Java people to read your code

Comment: Error:(7, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable car
  location: class CarFuel                                                                                  also Error:(8, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable car
  location: class CarFuelExec

Comment: Why are you doing `CarFuel.car = new CarFuel(0);`?

Comment: Change `CarFuel.car` to `CarFuel car`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Andrew because it calls the constructor to reset the starting fuel to 0.

Comment: Remove the period... `CarFuel   car = new...`

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft Full Of Eels.

Comment: Suggestion: Name your class `Car`, make the field be `int fuel`

Comment: Also, the method naming isn't typical of Java code - usually, [they are in camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CarFuelExec {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CarFuel car = new CarFuel(0);//make object of Car_Fuel
        car.GetGasoline(36);
        car.DrainGasoline(5);
        System.out.println("The remaining fuel in your car is: " + car.GetGasoline() + " gallons"); //method GetGasoline need parenparenthesis
    }
}
```

try this code it will work.....

Comment: @tobloef plz confirm what u have edited?i cant see any changes

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the code block, the first and last line were not being formatted. You can click on the "editied X hours ago" to view the changes.